# populate a drop down list data from database based on previous dropdown selection using PHP with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

the result that i want is show as
1.http://www.vaaah.com/php/view/DropDownList/13/How-to-populate-a-drop-down-based-on-previous-drop-down-selection-using-PHP-with-ajax
2.http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html

I had try it.but it didn't work. Can someone tell me where I getting wrong?
Appreciate with your help~

First I have Main.php

```
<?php
require("db_connection.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#state").change(function() {
    $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading     subcategory" /></div>');
    $.get('ajax-city.php?state=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#city").html(data);
        $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }); 
 });

 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form action="" method="get">
<fieldset>  
<legend style="color:black">Address Detail</legend> 
<table>

<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td> :</td>
<td> <select name="country" id="country" >
         <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            <?php
             if (isset ($db1)&&$db1!=""){

                }
             ?>
            <?php
                 $list=mysql_query("select * from delivery group by country     ");
                    while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_list['country']; ?>" <?php   if($row_list['country']==$db1){echo "selected"; } ?>>
                                 <?php echo $row_list['country'];?>                         </option>
                 <?php
                }
             ?>
        </select></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>State</td>
<td> :</td>
 <td> <select name="state" id="state" >
         <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
            <?php
             if (isset ($db1)&&$db1!=""){

                }
             ?>
            <?php
                 $list=mysql_query("select * from delivery group by state  ");
                    while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
            ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_list['state']; ?>"<?php  if($row_list['state']==$db1){echo "selected"; } ?>>
                                 <?php echo $row_list['state'];?>                           </option>
             <?php
                }
             ?>
        </select></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td> :</td>
<td> <select name="city2" id="city2" >

        </select></td>
</tr>

</table>
</fieldset>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax-city.php page

```
<?php

include('db_connection.php');

$id=$_GET['state'];
$sql=mysql_query("select * from delivery where state='$id' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<option value='$row[city]'>$row[city]</option>";
}


?>
```

Comment: it is a good practice to always wrap your `echo`s inside HTML with `htmlspecialchars` function in order to prevent XSS (Cross site scripting) issues when the data is entered by user

Comment: Do you get an error? If not, is there any data in the delivery table of your database?

Comment: there is no error shown.but the dropdown list for city didnt show out. in my database,there is a table delivery with country,state,city.